# Upgraded From NDK r10e to r21d --- Runtime Crash I Don't Understand

Tags: android, android-ndk

The crash happens when trying to new an object with a default constructor. I don't know what _Unwind_Resume is trying to tell me here.

********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:6.0.1/M4B30Z/3437181:user/release-keys'
#00 0x00041f50 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 0x0003fb5d /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
#02 0x0001c30f /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 0x000194c1 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
#04 0x000174ac /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 0x000e66f9 /data/app/com.my.package-1/lib/arm/libname.so
unwind_phase2(unw_context_t*, unw_cursor_t*, _Unwind_Control_Block*, bool)
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r21/external/libcxx/../../external/libunwind_llvm/src/Unwind-EHABI.cpp:648:9
#06 0x000e6797 /data/app/com.my.package-1/lib/arm/libname.so
_Unwind_Resume
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r21/external/libcxx/../../external/libunwind_llvm/src/Unwind-EHABI.cpp:715:3
#07 0x00073b28 /data/app/com.my.package-1/lib/arm/libname.so
AAA::BB::Create()
/gmae/AAA/src/BB.cpp:65:16
#08 0x00074bc8 /data/app/com.my.package-1/lib/arm/libname.so (Java_AAA_BB_create+8)
Java_AAA_BB_create
/AAA/src/jni_BB.cpp:20:7
#09 0x02f2f28d /data/app/com.my.package-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x14c5000) (void AAA.BB.create()+72)
#10 0x02f2f171 /data/app/com.my.package-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x14c5000) (void AAA.BB.()+76)

Comment: Making a guess, but it sounds like something in your `Create()` function raises an exception. If the full error message does not give any more useful indication, you could try the old-school printing to logcat all over the function to see how far the code gets before the crash occurs.

Comment: The usual answer to crashes during exception unwinding is that some library in your app is built incorrectly. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/BuildSystemMaintainers.md#Unwinding has the details, but unless you've written your own build scripts that's not normally relevant. How did you build your libraries? Do you depend on any prebuilt libraries?